# Best approach to detect iPad Safari user

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, mobile-safari

What is the best approach to add code for detecting an iPad Safari user. I mean should we use
1. CSS (through link media..)
2. JS (through navigator object)

I have heard that using user-agent string is not the best way to detect iPad, because of inconsistencies.

Please suggest. Thank you.

---

I also have a follow-up question;

Actually the code to detect desktop/iPad is going to be part of JSP (and not static HTML files)...Now in my app, there are 200+ pages..So where exactly should I be adding the code for detection and how exactly should I add it? I mean do I have to update somewhere in the servlet web.xml file..

Sorry for mixing the 2 questions..But just added here as both are related questions..

Comment: It totally depends on your use case. What exactly do you want to acieve by makingthis distiction? What about Android tablets?

Comment: That is what I am trying to detect..1) Device: iPad and 2) Browser: Mobile Safari..

Comment: @hmthur The main question still is **"What exactly do you want to acieve by it"**.

Comment: I want to apply different styles (through seperate CSS) for both desktop/iPad..

Comment: Please also see my updated follow-up question

Comment: changelog's answer contains what you need when styling. As of your JSP page, you have to search which file sets the header for the generated pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always have iPad in the user-agent.

However, if you're targeting iPads so that you can show things differently, then CSS media queries are definitely the way to go forward.

See [here](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/detect.js) how ZeptoJS detects iPad in JS.

To target iPad in both orientations, do this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="ipad-portrait.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="ipad-landscape.css">
```

Comment: Browser sniffing is usually not a good idea. I know special iPad sites I can use by changing the UA string in Firefox and Chrome. ;)

Comment: Heheh, I don't own one, so: no. You can't run other browsers on iPads? BTW, I've seen instances of older iPads with UA strings containing iPhone instead of iPad.

Comment: That's right. iOS version 3.2 reports iPad as being an iPhone. Didn't know about that one! However, I've got a feeling that you don't have lots of users on 3.2 at this point.

Comment: From what I understand, detecting through UA would not be 100% correct..Also through CSS, what code should I use to detect both iPad as well as orientation in a single statement..like I want to use seperate ipad_portrait.css and ipad_landscape.css . Please suggest.

Comment: I've added an example on how to target iPad on each orientation.

Comment: @changelog - you miss the point. Browser UA strings can be configured to look like Mobile Safari on iPad when they aren't. Using the UA string to "detect" the browser or platform is a bad strategy.

Comment: I have a question on using the media thing to detect...I mean when we use device-width, how can we be 100% sure that it is an iPad..For example, another tablet say Xoom may also satsify the width criteria..So is the media thing 100% reliable to detect ipad?