# Detection iPhone/iPad and changing CSS file

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad

How to detect and change css file iPad,iPhone3G and iPhone 4 with javascript

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect iPad users using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617638/detect-ipad-users-using-jquery)

Comment: Also see [Best approach to detect iPad Safari user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715717/best-approach-to-detect-ipad-safari-user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the CSS file based on the viewport width of device in this way:

< link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/css/ipad.css" type="text/css" media=" all and (min-width: 741px) and (max-width: 1024px)" title="no title" />

< link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/css/iphone.css" type="text/css" media=" all and (max-width: 740px)" title="no title" />

The code above checks the viewport width and decides which CSS file to use.